# Large file transfer with sockets

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client

When I'm transferring a large file using socket programming, the received file is incomplete i.e. it is an mp3 file which when i play sounds weird.
The code is:

**Server side:**

```
File myFile = new File("abc.mp3");
{
    Socket sock = servsock.accept();
    int packetsize=1024;
    double nosofpackets=Math.ceil(((int) myFile.length())/packetsize);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
    for(double i=0;i<nosofpackets+1;i++) {
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[packetsize];
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        System.out.println("Packet:"+(i+1));
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        os.write(mybytearray, 0,mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

**Client side:**

```
int packetsize=1024;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("zz.mp3");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
double nosofpackets=Math.ceil(((int) (new File("abc.mp3")).length())/packetsize);
for(double i=0;i<nosofpackets+1;i++)
{
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[packetsize];
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0,mybytearray.length );
    System.out.println("Packet:"+(i+1));
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0,mybytearray.length);
}
sock.close();
bos.close();
```

On the Client side I have used `new File("abc.mp3")).length` just for simplicity (I could send the length of the file from the server side).

This code works perfectly if client and server are the same machine, but the file gets distorted if they are on different machines.

Comment: If you have a buffered output stream, why are you manually buffereing it? Why don't you just read the entire thing in and write it all out at once?

Comment: isnt there a limit to the size of the buffer.So i m dividing the file into chunks n sending them.

Comment: @anonymous Of course there's a limit but you don't have to write all that to get chunked transfers. It will happen automatically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The canonical way to copy a stream in Java:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Works with any buffer size greater than zero. The temptation to relate the buffer size to the input size should be strenuously avoided.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the problem is that you are ignoring the values returned by various `read` calls, and assuming they completely fill the buffer.  This is problematic:

- When reading from a file, the *last* read probably won't fill the buffer.
- When reading from a socket, *any* read may return before filling the buffer.

The net result that your writes will put junk into the stream (at the server end), and into the destination file (at the client end).

Furthermore, it is pointless dividing the file up into chunks based on the size of the file.  Just read until you get to the end of file.

Answer (score 6):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use [`IOUtils.copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use packets.
Try using the ByteArrayOutputStream instead of using the static byte array.
keep reading from the inputstream until u reach EOF. n write each of this to the ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int byteToBeRead = -1;
while((byteToBeRead = is.read())!=-1){
baos.write(byteToBeRead);
}
byte[] mybytearray = baos.toByteArray();
bos.write(mybytearray, 0,mybytearray.length);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why? Arbitrary files don't necesarily fit into memory at all. It is better practice to assume they won't, and proceed accordingly. Your solution has nothing to recommend it: redundant initializations; added latency; unbounded memory costs; and it is more code than the alternative I posted that has none of these problems.

Comment: @EJP hw did u fix the size of the buffer??

Comment: @Sujay: it doesn't matter all that much. 8192 is a convenient number, not too big, not too small. The loop I posted will work for any buffer size > 0.

Comment: @Sujay:I tried your code on the client side, it gives a connection reset exception and also the file which is created on the client side is of size 1kb. I had come up with a soln, but there was a dataloss.What i did was replaced the for loop of defaultpacketsize on the server with a while loop (bis.available!=0) n on the client size the same loop excpet while(true). if the file was 5 mb then 4.95mb was only getting copied.

Comment: @EJP The read inside the while loop does not necessarily copy all the bytes being transfered by the client.I printed the count variable n each time a diff value was being printed.

Comment: @anonymous123: Of course it does. It copies exactly and every byte read until EOS. Your observation doesn't prove anything. The amount read per read can vary arbitrarily. Specifically, you cannot assume that the buffer was filled. What was the total bytecount transferred? And using available() in these loops is not correct. And if you are commenting on my answer you are doing so in the wrong place.