# Sending an image as a byte array between client and server

Tags: java, image, sockets

I can successfully send and draw a resized, 125 x 125 image from my client to my server. only problem is, thats way too small. I want to be able to send a larger image but the byte array can't handle it and I get a java heap exception. currently I'm using this to interpret my image. Is there a more efficient way?

On the client

```
screenShot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                screenShot = resize(screenShot, 125, 125);

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayO = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(screenShot,"PNG",byteArrayO);
                byte [] byteArray = byteArrayO.toByteArray();
                out.writeLong(byteArray.length);
                out.write(byteArray);
```

resize method as called above.

```
    public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {  
    int w = img.getWidth();  
    int h = img.getHeight();  
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType()); 
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();  
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);  
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);  
    g.dispose();  
    return dimg;  
   }
```

server that interprets the image

```
in = new DataInputStream(Client.getInputStream());
            long nbrToRead = in.readLong();
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) nbrToRead];
            int nbrRd = 0;
            int nbrLeftToRead = (int) nbrToRead;

            while (nbrLeftToRead > 0) {
                int rd = in.read(byteArray, nbrRd, nbrLeftToRead);
                if (rd < 0)
                    break;
                nbrRd += rd; // accumulate bytes read
                nbrLeftToRead -= rd;
            }
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayI = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    byteArray);
            image = ImageIO.read(byteArrayI);

            if (image != null) {
                paint(f.getGraphics(), image);
            } else {
                System.out.println("null image.");
            }
```

as you can tell the code is massive and most likely inefficient. I could send 1/10 of the image 10 times for with and height, drawing on those parts instead but I wanted to know if there was an easier way to do this.

Comment: I think this is somewhat similar with this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113914/large-file-transfer-with-sockets

Comment: thats similar to what I'm doing but my byte array is just too large to handle anything > 125x125

Comment: I' trying to avoid having to read the screen in multiple pieces

Comment: do you need to send it as a byte array? that is what is creating your size restriction. Why not send it as an object over an object stream.

Comment: I can do that? how so? and how would I convert it back to a `BufferedImage`?

Comment: If bufferedImage was serializable, it would have worked like magic, but it isn't. So use MemoryCacheImageOutputStream instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably think of transferring data as stream over the network. You can make use of third-party libraries like [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/) . In case you can make data transfer using web service then you can look at Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) which lets you transfer data as stream in more efficient manner. For more details please have a look [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/adhirmehta/archive/2010/06/11/transferring-large-binary-data-web-services)

Comment: I'll take a look at that later, but that seems to be what I need after briefly reading over it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
public class ImageClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException {

    BufferedImage screenShot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",11111);
    MemoryCacheImageOutputStream byteArrayO = new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ImageIO.write(screenShot, "PNG", byteArrayO);
    byteArrayO.flush();
    socket.close();
  }

}


public class ImageServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(11111);
        try{
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            MemoryCacheImageInputStream ois = new MemoryCacheImageInputStream(is);
            ImageIO.read(ois);
            s.close();
        }finally{
            ss.close();
        }
   }
}
```