# Efficient way to send object over socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, object

right now i am sending object like below.

```
Class msg{
  private byte[] byte;
  private String msg;
  public setbyte(byte[] b){byte=b;}
  public byte[] getbyte(){return byte;}

}
```

..............................................................................

```
Socket mSocket;
msg mMsg=new msg();
mSocket = new Socket();
mSocket.bind(null);
mSocket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(mPeerIP, Constants.WELCOME_SOCKET_PORT)), 3000);
mOut = new ObjectOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
mOut.writeObject(mMsg);
mOut.flush();
```

Here mMsg is an object.
But my socket get crash when i send heavy file above 50Mb.
Is there any efficient way to send this object over socket.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113914/large-file-transfer-with-sockets

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard i have to send object so do i need to convert it to bytes then send ?

Comment: *"I stored files in a bytes"*, I assumed that you already have the byte array.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard so i have to send object only...becs object has string and byte both

Comment: You can easily convert your object to byte array : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Is it also correct if i make my class  parcelable and then just send  my object.

Comment: With big files, you will have to send chunks instead of entire file. There is plenty of example here on Stack Overflow, just type in something like "Sending huge file over network java" in the search box.